# pip on Python 2.7 in RHEL using yum

Tags: linux, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, pip

I have tried to install `pip` for Python 2.7 on RHEL using `sudo yum install python3-pip`, and, while the installation gets completed, when I try to run `pip` it says that command is not found.

- `yum list installed | grep pip` shows the following:

  ```
  libpipeline.x86_64                  1.2.3-3.el7                   @anaconda/7.2
  python3-pip.noarch                  9.0.3-7.el7_8                 @os
  ```
- `which pip` returns:

  ```
  no pip in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ME/.local/bin:/home/Me/bin)
  ```

Comment: why didn't you install python2-pip?

Comment: tried yum install python27-python-pip but same

Comment: well, I have a CentOS and it worked with `yum install python-pip` as the system finds the correct version to install to. what is the output of `yum info python2-pip`

Comment: yum info python2-pip -->
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Error: No matching Packages to list
But python3-pip gives output

Comment: so it is not installed, please try the following: 1. remove the pip3, 2. yum clean, 3. install with `yum install python-pip` and let us know if you have pip

Answer (score 0):

The `python3-pip` package installs `/usr/bin/pip3`, so simply invoke it as `pip3`, and *not* `pip`.

That of course, means you're going to use Python 3 version.

For Python 2 version, install `python2-pip` and launch it as either `pip2`, or simply `pip`.

I hope it's needless to say that you shouldn't be later using `pip` as root, as this is going to ruin your system sooner or later. Set up a virtualenv and use `pip` there.

Comment: I have no idea why pip can ruin the system. Wy cant I use pip as root?

Comment: It's pretty simple: most distros package Python modules using their own mechanism, be it `rpm` or `deb` packages. When you run `pip` as root you're essentially using completely different mechanism to those, but the location of the modules is the same, so it will overwrite `rpm`/`deb` ones. Why it's bad is because there is a whole eco-system of `rpm`/`deb` packaged modules/apps and they are often work with specific versions of modules. With `pip` in use, you're bringing in often a newer version of a module that breaks dependent programs. Just use `yum`, or else use virtualenv.

Comment: Check out the post explaining [why pip should never be run as root](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root), and solutions.